Moveit with UR and onrobot gripper attached in ros2
I'm trying to attach an onrobot gripper to an ur10e and plan paths using moveit. I followed this tutorial to attach the urdf-file of the onrobot gripper (rg6) found here to the robot. I ran the moveit_setup_assisstant to generate moveit_config files. When launching the demo.launch.py rviz opens (with warnings*), and I am able to plan paths while execution fails (with errors**): 
*warnings:
[spawner-6] [FATAL] [1721227947.103989133] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed loading controller joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-5] [FATAL] [1721227947.129944879] [spawner_scaled_joints_trajectory_controller]: Failed loading controller scaled_joints_trajectory_controller
**errors:
[ERROR] [move_group-2]: process has died [pid 72023, exit code -11, cmd '/home/finn/ros2_humble_wss/ws_moveit2_humble/install/moveit_ros_move_group/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_d7bagell --params-file /tmp/launch_params_itpo00j8'].
From my understanding I need to load the UR-Polyscope as well as the UR driver, which I did with the following commands:

ros2 run ur_client_library start_ursim.sh -m ur10e

Activate robot and run UR-Cap external control

ros2 launch ur_robot_driver ur_control.launch.py ur_type:=ur10e robot_ip:=192.168.56.101 launch_rviz:=false


ros2 launch ur_moveit_config ur_moveit.launch.py ur_type:=ur10e launch_rviz:=true description_package:=th_cell description_file:=my_robot_cell.urdf.xacro moveit_config_package:=moveit_config_th_cell moveit_config_file:=my_robot_cell.srdf.xacro

(With a small modfications to the srdf file so it is a srdf.xacro file and uses a macro just like here)
Where is my error? Do I need to code my own launch file?
Thanks in advance. If you need more insights, let me know.
I am aware of this repo, but it uses ros1 and is of no help.
